# Paypal integration with iOS sdk

Tags: ios, paypal

I have down loaded Pay pal SDK latest version 1.1.0. It is working fine with the testing environment  but while using for  sandbox account it is throwing an error saying "There was problem communicating with paypal servers".Can you please  help ? I  am integrating paypal with iOS  app. **the response on the console is:**

```
PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1555:19d03] Request has failed with error:"pp_service_error_json_parse_error - System error. Please try again later.
details: (
        {
        "ns_error" = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)\" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0xa456590 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}";
    }
)"
```

Comment: Check PayPal sandbox endpoint url. Is it correct to make call to PayPal sandbox server?

Comment: In the documentation it is just mentioned just to change the environment to use sandbox account  nothing more is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

@Kiran:

Dave from PayPal here.

1. Could you please provide the details of the payment you were trying to submit (currency code, amount, short description)?
2. Was this attempted transaction a PayPal or credit card payment?
3. At what stage in the flow did this error occur?

Once I have that information, I'll try to reproduce your scenario and get back to you.

Comment: PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
  payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"9.95"];
  payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
  payment.shortDescription = @"Hipster t-shirt";

Immediately after Launching the app and clicking no the"Buy" in the iOS 6.1 simulator,I am getting the error.Need immediate help please.

Comment: @Kiran sorry for my delay in seeing your response. There have apparently been some transient failures of the Sandbox server over the past few weeks. Are you still running into this problem now?

Comment: hi@DaveGoldman i am getting issue "pp_service_error_json_parse_error - System error. Please try again later. (403) | Details: (
".can you please help?

Comment: Sorry, @KrutarthPatel -- I'm no longer working at PayPal. I suggest that you contact PayPal's developer support group.

Comment: @DaveGoldman Thanks for response.but i want to know why i am getting issue